# A struct for recording audio samples

Tags: c++, object-oriented, audio

I am writing a program in c++ to record audio.
Here are my structure and code snippet.

```
typedef struct _recorder {
    const uint32_t SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    const uint32_t FRAME_STEP = SAMPLE_RATE / 100;
    const uint32_t STEP_BUF_SIZE = sizeof(int16_t) * FRAME_STEP;
    int16_t *step_buf;

    const uint32_t RECORD_TIME = 10;
    const uint32_t NUM_SAMPLE = RECORD_TIME * SAMPLE_RATE;
    int16_t *total_buf;

    uint32_t sample_counter;
} recorder;

void recorder_init(recorder *r)
{
    r->step_buf = new int16_t[r->STEP_BUF_SIZE / sizeof(int16_t)];
    r->total_buf = new int16_t[r->NUM_SAMPLE];
}

void recorder_free(recorder *r)
{
    delete[] r->step_buf;
    delete[] r->total_buf;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    recorder rec;
    recorder_init(&rec);

    // Do something to record audio

    recorder_free(&rec);
}
```

Does using structures and functions make sense to you? Or should I use a class? Or there are better design patterns I can follow?

EDIT -------------------------
I add a further question of this post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178375/a-c-classs-for-recording-audio-samples).

Comment: You are assuming 16 bit samples, but in the real world, 24 bit hardware (and even 32 bit) are common.

Answer (score 13):

This is very much C-style code: the only thing that qualifies it as C++ is the fact that you use `new` and `delete[]` rather than `malloc()` and `free()`.

I don't see why `RECORD_TIME` should be a constant. I would expect it to be a constructor parameter. Or, use `std::vector` to store the samples, and you won't even have to worry about the array capacity, or even `new` and `delete[]`.

The recorder class should be responsible for initializing `sample_counter` to zero, which you never did in your `recorder_init()`. In addition, I would expect there to be a method for appending a sample, and that method would automatically increment `sample_counter`. Again, though, if you used a `std::vector`, you wouldn't need such a complication, since the vector's size would serve that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

There's not very much difference between `struct`s and `class`es in C++. `struct`s can have methods and `protected` and `private` data, for example.

But given what you've posted above, I think it makes more sense to make the above functions be methods of a `class` or `struct`. This allows you to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), for example. The constructor and destructor would do what `recorder_init()` and `recorder_free()` do.

Comment: When you mention `struct` in C++, it's worthwhile to mention that you don't need `typedef struct fakename { } correctname` but can and should write `struct correctname`. This is important when you add member functions.

Comment: I strongly dislike having to explicitly write `struct` before every use of the type, so personally prefer the older way of using a `typedef` or the newer `using` syntax.

Comment: So did the creators of C++, which is why you don't need the typedef in *any* version of C++.

Comment: Ah, you're saying that you only need the keyword `struct` in the type definition, then and not when declaring a variable of that type? I wasn't aware of that. Good to know!

Comment: It's more than you suggest: **C++ does not have structs**. C++ only has the `struct` *keyword*, and `struct Foo { … }` is *identical* to `class Foo { public: … }`.

Comment: @wchargin ... *identical* with the exception of **default visibility** - *public* vs *private*.

Comment: @vaxquis: Right, that's why I wrote `struct Foo { … }` vs `class Foo { public: … }`; am I missing something?

Comment: @wchargin saying they are simply interchangeable just by adding `public:` in the start of the body is quite misleading to newbies - see e.g. https://ideone.com/O8HOmx ; if `Foo` inherits from anything (which it quite probably can), the default access will differ, making the entire inheritance act differently. Using `public:` doesn't change the default access (you'd have to also use `Foo : public base` instead of `Foo : base` etc.) - so because there *are* caveats here, I wouldn't ever say they are *exactly* interchangeable.