# A c++ classs for recording audio samples

Tags: c++, object-oriented, audio

This question is a continuation of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178348/a-struct-for-recording-audio-samples).

Here, I modified the original code with the following changes.
1. Make a `class Recorder()` to store the information of audio data.

```
class Recorder {
    public:
        Recorder(uint32_t sample_rate, uint32_t rec_time);
        ~Recorder();
        uint32_t frame_step;
        uint32_t sample_rate;
        uint32_t step_buf_size;
        uint32_t num_sample;
        uint32_t sample_counter;
        uint32_t record_time;
        int16_t *total_buf;
        void append(int16_t *step_buf, uint32_t n);
    private:
};

Recorder::Recorder(uint32_t rate, uint32_t rec_time)
{
    sample_rate = rate;
    frame_step = sample_rate / 100;
    step_buf_size = sizeof(int16_t) * frame_step;
    num_sample = rec_time * sample_rate;
    record_time = rec_time;
    sample_counter = 0;
    total_buf = new int16_t[num_sample];
}

Recorder::~Recorder()
{
    delete[] total_buf;
}

void Recorder::append(int16_t *step_buf, uint32_t n)
{
    memcpy(&total_buf[sample_counter], step_buf, n);
    sample_counter += n;
}
```

2. Use the following code to save a *.wav file.

```
static int32_t DumpWav(char fname[], int16_t lpsSample[], uint32_t nNumSample, uint32_t nSampleRate)
{   // arrays passed to functions are converted to pointers.
    class WavFile wf;
    wf.Create(fname, 1, 16, nSampleRate);
    if (lpsSample != NULL && nNumSample > 0) {
        wf.Write((BYTE *)lpsSample, nNumSample * 2);
        wf.Flush();
    }
    return nNumSample;
}
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Recorder rec(44100, 10);
    class CWaveRecord oRecorder;

    // Here I have to use new, because It's not allow to use a variable to init array.
    // int16_t tmp_buf[sizeof(uint16_t) * rec.frame_step]; <-- this does not compile.
    int16_t *step_buf = new int16_t[sizeof(uint16_t) * rec.frame_step];

    // Do something to record audio
    oRecorder.Initialize(1, 16, rec.sample_rate, rec.step_buf_size, 300, NULL, 0); // 0.01 * 300 = 3s circular buffer
    char ch;
    while (1) {
        printf("Press any key to record , and press again to stop, 'q' to exit ...\nMaximum recording time is %d seconds.\n", rec.record_time);
        ch = _getch();
        if (ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q' || ch == 27)
            break;

        printf("Start Record ...\n");
        rec.sample_counter = 0;

        oRecorder.StartRecord();
        while (oRecorder.GetWave((unsigned char *)step_buf) == WR_ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            uint32_t n;
            n = oRecorder.GetSamplePerBuffer();
            if (rec.sample_counter < rec.num_sample) {
                //rec.append(step_buf, sizeof(uint16_t) * n); <-- This line doesn't work. Why?
                memcpy(&rec.total_buf[rec.sample_counter], step_buf, sizeof(uint16_t) * n);
                rec.sample_counter += n;
            } else {
                oRecorder.StopRecord();
                printf("Buffer is empty. Done\n");
                break;
            }

        }

        char lpszFileName[256];
        SYSTEMTIME time;
        GetLocalTime(&time);
        sprintf_s(lpszFileName, "cmd_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d_%02d.wav", time.wMonth, time.wDay, time.wHour, time.wMinute, time.wSecond, 1);
        DumpWav(lpszFileName, rec.total_buf, rec.sample_counter, rec.sample_rate);
    }

    delete[] step_buf;
}
```

This block of code works on my PC, but I still have few questions.
1. Why is my Recorder::append not working?
2. I didn't use `vector()` to store my audio data. The reason is that I have to pass address of `total_buf` to `memcpy()` and `DumpWav()`. Is using vector possible here to replace array?
3. Do you see any other improvements of my code?
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to pick up a good, or at least reasonably decent C++ book. StackOverflow has a big list. I say this because you write `void main`, which is a clear sign that you have a poor book (it's `int main()` - different return type, and you're not using arc/argv)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of things here you should definitely improve on:

1. Where are your includes? Your first file is missing the includes for `cstdint` and `cstring`, your second file for `cstdint`, `cstdio`, whatever header `WavFile` belongs to, the header for `CWaveRecorder`, for `SYSTEMTIME` and so on and so forth. It's a miracle that your code even compiles successfully.
2. Everything from standard headers must be prefixed with `std::`. This applies to all the `[u]int**_t` types as well as to `printf`, `memcpy`, etc.
3. `class WavFile wf;` is superfluous; `Wavfile wf;` will do fine. This is not C.
4. Why do you bother with `printf`, `_getch` and the like? This is C++, and it has a standard library that offers a great range of very handy tools for such things, such as `std::cout` and `std::cin`. Don't reinvent the wheel. Again, *this is not C*.
5. Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`. *This is not C*.
6. Why does `Recorder` have a `private:` followed by nothing? Remove that.
7. Why are all of `Recorder`'s member variables public? This violates data encapsulation. Instead, provide getters and setters for data that should be accessible to the public.
8. To answer the second question of yours: Yes, it is perfectly possible here to use `std::vector` and you should definitely opt to do so. First of all, `std::vector` provides a method named `data()` which allows access to the underlying array. Secondly, there is also `std::copy`, which you should prefer in almost all cases.

---

This answer is by far not comprehensive, but I suggest you go and rework your code, then come back for another review.

I am not going to sugarcoat it for you: Your code is *horrible* by C++ standards. You freely mix C legacy functions with code bearing only the slightest resemblance with what is called modern C++.

There is a middle ground between C and C++ which is called "C with classes" by most people. If you want to write code that's closer to C, you could consider sticking with that. Otherwise, I **strongly** recommend you to pick up a good book and learn how to write reasonably good C++ first.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>` adds a lot of functionality to arrays, but at the core it's still a `T[]` array. In particular, `&vec[n] == &vec[0] + n` just like arrays. `memcpy` will therefore work. Having said that, C++ uses `std::copy`.

Other things: `WavFile::Create` is an oddity. In C++, objects are created by the constructor.